# Seleção da pasta de Downloads em vez do projeto no PphStorm

Tags: download, phpstorm, diretório

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Eu baixei o PhpStorm e fui selecionar o projeto que estava dentro da pasta de Downloads. Nisso, eu acabei selecionando a "Downloads" e meu problema agora é que o que eu baixo não é reconhecido.
Na pasta ficou um arquivo chamado ".idea" que é algo que o PhpStorm gerou.
Gostaria de ajuda para tirar esse arquivo e voltar ao normal a minha pasta de Downloads.
Já desinstalei o PhpStorm, e não sei se só apagar o arquivo .idea resolveria.

(Não sei se os arquivos estão dando erro ao abrir mesmo, ou é só impressão por conta desse símbolo no arquivo do excel.)

Comment: Boa noite Isabela, seja bem vinda! Então não é para dar problema por conta da pasta **.idea**, lá vai conter arquivos que ajudam o **phpstorm** na indexação do projeto configurações e entre outros, você pode excluir sem problema, já tentou baixar outra coisa e abrir?

Comment: Olá obrigada, agora está normalizado.